# Why do drive letters make this VBA code fail in Excel 2010?

Tags: vba, excel

An excel workbook that I maintain has this VBA code in it:

```
Function GetDrivePath(DriveLetter As String) As String
Dim DrivePath As String
Dim DriveLen As Long

'DrivePath = Space(260)
DriveLen = Len(DrivePath)

If WNetGetConnection(DriveLetter, DrivePath, DriveLen) = error_success Then
    GetDrivePath = DrivePath
Else
    GetDrivePath = DriveLetter
End If
End Function
```

Up until recently this code worked fine, but now it fails. Even in archived versions of the excel sheet from the time period where it did work, it no longer works.

It is not called if a path in this format is used in the excel workbook:

```
\\servername\filepath
```

But it is called when paths have drive letters:

```
X:\filepath
```

Now it fails whenever it is called. It never had this issue before.

The code is supposed to return the server path that the drive letter refers to.

The error that it returns is not particularly useful; it is a simple type mismatch error.

---

**Typical Input:**

```
X:
```

where "X" is a drive letter.

**Typical Output:**

```
\\servername\path-to-folder-that-X-is-mapped-to
```

**Declare Statement:**

```
Declare Function WNetGetConnection Lib "mpr.dll" Alias "WNetGetConnectionA" (ByVal lpszLocalName As String, ByVal lpszRemoteName As String, cbRemoteName As Long) As Long
```

Comment: What does `WNetGetConnection` do? Can you show us that code too?

Comment: @aphoria it is a Microsoft function.

Comment: Here's [Microsoft's info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385453(v=vs.85).aspx) about it.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more on what input you are giving it and what output you are expecting versus what output you are getting?

Comment: You're not using WNetGetConnection correctly. It doesn't return a `BOOL`, but a numeric result. It returns `NO_ERROR` if it's successful, and a system error code if it fails that tells you why. You need to be checking the result properly. (This is clearly stated in the very same documentation you linked in your comment above. The error values are all the ones listed that start with `ERROR_`.) You've also commented out the line that allocates space for the information - uncomment the `DrivePath = Space(260)` line. If your network path is long, you'll need to use `WNetGetUniversalName` instead.

Comment: @KenWhite I have not done any of this. This is in place code that I am maintaining. It has worked this way for years.

Comment: @called2voyage: That's nice. It's been wrong for years, and clearly isn't working now or you wouldn't be posting here. **Read the documentation** that you yourself linked for yourself. As I said, it's stated quite clearly: It returns a `DWORD`, and the `Return Value` section says "If the function succeeds, the return value is NO_ERROR. If the function fails, the return value is a system error code, such as one of the following values."

Comment: @aphoria I have added typical input and output.

Comment: @KenWhite I have already tried editing the code to conform to that document as you suggested and it returns the same error.

Comment: What is the **specific value** it is returning? "it is a simple type mismatch error" is not one of the return values for `WNetGetConnection`.

Comment: @KenWhite It will not show the actual error value that the WNetGetConnection returns. It only shows the excel type mismatch error.

Comment: What line is the error occurring on?

Comment: @aphoria "If WNetGetConnection(DriveLetter, DrivePath, DriveLen) = error_success Then"

Comment: It will show it if the call is being made to WNetGetConnection. Declare an integer value (eg., `Res`), and then use it: `Res = WNetGetConnection(...)`. You can do whatever you need to with `Res` after the call to determine what's wrong.

Comment: @KenWhite Res never gets a value; it just throws the type mismatch error.

Comment: The problem is that you're not calling it properly. It expects to get a drive letter in the format `X:`, not a single character `X`. Passing a single character results in a return value of `ERROR_BAD_DEVICE`, which you would know if you were checking it. :-) It also needs the line with the `DrivePath = Space(260)` uncommented, as I said before, so that there's space allocated for the UNC (network) name.

Comment: @KenWhite I do have the drive letter in the format "X:" and I have already tried uncommenting that line and it still fails.

Comment: Show us the `Declare Function .. Lib` statement that defines this external library call to VBA.

Comment: @RBarryYoung There you go!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was actually not in the library that this code relied on, but in a different reference.

Office 2007 has a control called Microsoft Calendar Control that no longer exists in Office 2010. This control was still being referenced in the VBA Code reference dialog, that looks similar to but not exactly like this:

[image: Missing control]

To remedy this I went into the VBA Code viewer, opened the Tools drop-down menu and clicked References. This brings up a dialog similar to the above. I simply unchecked the missing reference (which wasn't even being used in this excel workbook) and clicked OK. This immediately cleared up all problems.

Notably, it even works with the original code, which is reportedly "wrong".

Answer (score 3):

I know you say it used to work, but I don't see how the code you posted could have ever worked.

Try this...and this assumes that `error_success` is defined as a global variable or constant.

The variable `DrivePath` has to be pre-formatted as string full of spaces...otherwise `WNetGetConnection` cannot use it to return the UNC path.

```
Public Function GetDrivePath(DriveLetter As String) As String
  Dim DrivePath As String
  Dim DriveLen As Long

  DriveLen = 255
  DrivePath = Space(DriveLen)

  If WNetGetConnection(DriveLetter, DrivePath, DriveLen) = error_success Then
    GetDrivePath = DrivePath
  Else
    GetDrivePath = DriveLetter
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: This I think is getting somewhere. Now it gives a missing library error.

Comment: Strangely, I have located and confirmed that mpr.dll is still on my computer.

Comment: Is `MPR.DLL` in a folder that is in your `PATH`?

Comment: Yes, it is...strange.

Comment: aphoria, I've fixed the issue. See my answer.